# How can I create a page that links to all articles with fake long titles?

Tags: articles, category, component-configuration

I would like to have a page that lists all articles in a category by subcategory, and to have these articles listed by titles longer than Joomla's built-in maximum length.

In asking [this question](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/21340/9145) I found out that changing Joomla's built in maximum length is a very bad idea, but that there are ways to "fake" long article titles in links to lists of articles.

**How can I create a page that lists articles in a category by subcategory with "fake" titles that are longer than Joomla's built-in article length limit?**

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this with the built in functionality of Joomla.

- Create a **Category Blog Menu Item** and deactivate title under the options tab.
- While creating an article, write first your fake title and maybe a short intro text.
- Then use the "**read more**" button on the bottom of the editor to insert the read more button (displayed as line in the editor).
- Then you can write your main content of the article.

https://docs.joomla.org/Splitting_an_Article_into_an_introduction_with_a_link_to_read_more

Answer (score 0):

You can do a template override for the category view and instead of displaying a title in HREF use the intro part of each article that is displayed above the fold.

Comment: Could you go into more detail about how to do this?